# A metaphor which can introduce an experienced/inexperienced person

Tags: word-request, expressions, metaphors

What do you call a half-baked (not quite experienced) and well-baked (well-experienced) person in English?

I'm looking for a metaphorical expression or preferably word, which can explain a person who has or has not experienced ups and downs of life and subsequently not able to decide, act, behave properly when it comes to.

> - Don't shout at him. Try not to blame him this much. He's just a .............. young person. I think the only person who understands our son is your father. This is why everyone calls him a....................... [said wife to her husband privately about their son].

The only words that come to mind are:

> 1) mature/immature 
>   2) experienced/inexperienced

Although both pairs work properly in the blanks, but as I mentioned, I need some metaphors to explain such people.
I wonder if you let me know about it.

It could be great if "half-baked" and "baked" could sound natural in this sense. :))

Comment: Look up synonyms for [fledgling](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fledgling)

Comment: That's strange @CowperKettle! Because there can be dozens of words which would work, but in this specific case I need to know what would a native speaker say! Otherwise, I could just check any dictionary and find some words which could be obsolete or unnatural! Also please note that as I mentioned, I was looking for a metaphor rather than just a single word.

Comment: "a babe in the woods"?

Comment: Well @CowperKetle your offer is so simmilar to someone who is still green, and not that formal that I need it to be! Moreover, I needed to know something opposit to that too, as it is required to fill in the further blank. I don't want too formal cases! Just something to be used in everyday speech would be enough.